# Octave java invalid call to script

Tags: java, matlab, ubuntu, octave

Issue with Octave and java.  Not sure if I am connecting java to octave correctly for this.

```
url = java.net.URL(urlString); %%this works in matlab
error: invalid call to script /home/xxx/octave/java-1.2.9/java.m
```

---

But the following examples works:

```
octave> s = javaObject ("java.lang.String", "Hello OctaveString")
  s = Hello OctaveString
```

---

```
octave> v = javaObject ("java.util.Vector")
  v =
    <Java object: java.util.Vector>
octave> v.add(12);
octave> v.get(0)
  ans = 12
```

---

```
octave> d = javaObject ("java.lang.Double", 12.34)
  d = 12.340
```

---

I have installed Octave3.8.0 using:  http://blogs.bu.edu/mhirsch/2013/12/compiling-octave-3-8/comment-page-1/#comment-12930

This link has been helpful too:  http://wiki.octave.org/Java_package

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `javaObject("java.net.URL")` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit syntax `java.net.URL(urlString)` is not possible, at least in the version i tested. You have to create every object via `javaObject`

```
url = javaObject('java.net.URL',urlString);
```

Comment: when I remove the semicolon... i get back:  url =

<Java object: java.net.URL>

Comment: You get it in both cases, the semicolon only suppresses the output.